# Execution failed for task generateJsonModelArmDebug

Tags: android, gradle, cmake

I try to use Android Studio to build native c++ project using cmake 3.14.0 version. Like in documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code#use_a_custom_cmake_version . So I add `version "3.14.0"` to my build.gradle and add `cmake.dir=C\:\\CMakeWin32` to my local.properties about vanilla cmake. 
And then:

```
> Task :UnitTests:generateJsonModelArmDebug
> Task :UnitTests:generateJsonModelArmDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':UnitTests:generateJsonModelArmDebug'.
> Illegal char <:> at index 47: C:/j/client/dava.framework/Programs/UnitTests\C:/r15c/sources/android/cpufeatures/cpu-features.c
```

If I use default cmake 3.6 in NDK bundle all works. My environment is:
Windows        - 10 
Android Studio - 3.4.1 
gradle         - try 4.10.1 and 5.4.1 
ndk            - try 15c and 19c

In my CMakeLists.txt I add dependency:

```
    add_library( ${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${PLATFORM_ADDED_SRC} ${REMAINING_LIST} )
    include(AndroidNdkModules)
    android_ndk_import_module_cpufeatures()
    target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} cpufeatures)
```

I understand from error message full path to `C:/r15c/sources/android/cpufeatures/cpu-features.c` gradle want's to concatenate with path to current project `C:/j/client/dava.framework/Programs/UnitTests`. I think problem with gradle and how it use cmake_server to generate json code model. But how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Update(more info):

1. If I build like: `C:\j\client\dava.framework\Programs\UnitTests\Platforms\Android>gradlew :UnitTests:generateJsonModelArmDebug --info > log.txt 2>&1`
2. in log file copy responce from cmake server and save it in file test.json
3. open test.json in Firefox and see target libcpufeatures.a in `source` section has full path to one source file.
4. `sourceDirectory` remainse from parent project `C:/j/client/dava.framework/Programs/UnitTests`
5. so I think gradle try to combine this two together bug in cmake or in gradle work with json responce from cmake.
   [image: json view of responce from cmake-server]

Comment: Can you please post more of the code that is relevant to the error, it is hard to understand where the error is coming from. Can you post your gradle file or other files to help illuminate where this concatenation is happening?

Comment: add issue to cmake https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/19288

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug was in google gradle plugin so I just upgrade it and it works with new cmake 3.14.
Just update your gradle plugin:

```
    dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1' }
```